# How to apply transformation in a specific portion of a texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, transformation

Lets say i have a rectangle

[image]

Now i wish to apply it transformations such as translating in the z direction and scalling as well on the lower-right corner of the texture.

[image]

How can i do that. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what we call curl page effect.
no build-in support is provided by android .
although you can implement your own by following any tutorials . search for curl page .
one good link [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/)

Answer (score 0):

> Now i wish to apply it transformations such as translating in the z direction and scalling as well on the lower-right corner of the texture.

A rectangle hat exactly 4 vertices. A transformation moves around vertices. The effect you try to implement is a so called "page curl" and doesn't work on a rectangle. You need a grid for this, so that you have enough vertices to curl it.